# cordova-plugin-file.fileSystems not found on line 0 for undefined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I try to use `cordova-plugin-file`, but after install this plugin and run it in `cordova-sim`, I got this error

```
!JavaScript ERROR: module cordova-plugin-file.fileSystems not found on line 0 for undefined
```

if you've experienced the same thing, please tell me why, and how to solve it.

Thank you,
**Best Regard**